# Heroku Deploy: dash.exceptions.NoLayoutException

Tags: python, heroku, plotly, plotly-dash

I attempting to deploy a multi-tab dash app to Heroku server, however I get a `dash.exceptions.NoLayoutException`. I am following the Structuring a Multi-Page App example here: https://dash.plotly.com/urls

The App works fine locally and I am able to run it with `python index.py` and `gunicorn index:server` commands.

My file structure looks like this:

```
index.py
app.py
requirements.txt
Procfile
Tabs
--- Tab1.py
--- Tab2.py
assets
--- style.css
```

The contents of app.py :

```
import dash
import flask
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc


app = dash.Dash(__name__, suppress_callback_exceptions=True)
server = app.server

app = dash.Dash(
            meta_tags=[
                {"name": "viewport", "content": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1"}
            ],
            external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.SLATE],
      )
```

Contents of index.py

```
import pandas as pd
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
import plotly as py
from plotly import graph_objs as go
from plotly.graph_objs import *
import flask
from app import app
import os
from tabs import reporting, portfolio, market, deal, revenue, comps, analysis

# In[8]:
server = app.server

# App Layout

app.layout = html.Div([

    # header
    html.Div([

        html.H2("Product"),
    ),

    # tabs
    html.Div([

        dcc.Tabs(

            id="tabs",
            
            children=[

                 dcc.Tab(label="Port", value="p_tab"),
                 dcc.Tab(label="Leads", value="r_tab"),
              
            ],
            
        )

        ],

        className="row tabs_div"

    ),

        # Tab content
        html.Div(id="tab_content"),

])

# In[9]:

# Render tabs/subtabs
@app.callback(
                Output("tab_content", "children"),

              [
                  Input("tabs", "value"),
                  Input("subtabs", "value")
              ],
             )
def render_content(tab, subtab):
    """
    For user selections, return the relevant tab
    """
    if tab == "p_tab":
        return tab1.layout

    if tab == "r_tab":
        return tab2.layout

    else:
        return (dash.no_update)

# In[10]:

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Production
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Traceback

```
2020-08-13T04:23:11.192175097Z app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-08-13T04:23:11.192180799Z app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
2020-08-13T04:23:11.192185482Z app[web.1]:     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2020-08-13T04:23:11.192189928Z app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1945, in full_dispatch_request
2020-08-13T04:23:11.192194507Z app[web.1]:     self.try_trigger_before_first_request_functions()
2020-08-13T04:23:11.192198903Z app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1993, in try_trigger_before_first_request_functions
2020-08-13T04:23:11.192203399Z app[web.1]:     func()
2020-08-13T04:23:11.192207530Z app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 1500, in _setup_server
2020-08-13T04:23:11.192212198Z app[web.1]:     self._validate_layout()
2020-08-13T04:23:11.192216422Z app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/dash/dash.py", line 1465, in _validate_layout
2020-08-13T04:23:11.192220923Z app[web.1]:     "The layout was `None` "
2020-08-13T04:23:11.192225366Z app[web.1]: dash.exceptions.NoLayoutException: The layout was `None` at the time that `run_server` was called. Make sure to set the `layout` attribute of your application before running the server.
```

Comment: try changing the procfile to `gunicorn index:app.server`

Comment: This fixed the issue.

Comment: I have the same problem. I've changed everything to be like in the example above, but when I run gunicorn index:app.server, I get" Failed to parse 'app.server' as an attribute name or function call."

Comment: make sure it's `web:gunicorn index:app.server`

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me:

index.py

```py
from app import app, server
```

app.py

```py
server = app.server
```

Procfile

```
web: gunicorn index:server
```

---

Apparently, that multi-app example you linked to, the one in the offical Dash docs, has a mistake.  Gunicorn doesn't accept the syntax, `<file>:<variable>.<sub-variable>`. This forum thread pointed me towards this solution:

https://community.plotly.com/t/deploy-dash-to-heroku-error-failed-to-parse-app-server-as-an-attribute-name-or-function-call/47909